# Using expo-av library in react-native application, how to avoid a sound delay when tapped on <TouchableOpacity> component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am trying to create an app using react native expo and I was adding sounds to the buttons using expo-av library. So my intention is to play a sound when tapped on the touchableOpacity component. So I initially used OnPress property and then changed to onPressIn, thinking it would make a difference. But it didn't.

There is a significant delay between the sound and the tap. close to 1 second.

I tried calling the function using the useEffect hook, in order to load the sound and then playing the sound using the useState hook. But the delay persisted.

```
async function playsoundone(){
  const {sound}  = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require('../../assets/music/noteone.aac'));
  await  sound.playAsync();   
}

return(
  <TouchableOpacity onPressIn={()=>playsoundone()} >
    <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:80, }}>Tap</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

I tried reducing the file size of the audio by changing the bitrate but it didn't affect the delay.

I tried increasing the bufferSize to 102400 as suggested by the Bard, but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have was able to reduce the delay to an extend it sound it does play the moment I tap the button by importing the audio to Audacity and cutting out the initial delay from the audio itself (which might have been the reason for the delay, the whole time, but changing the sample rate and bit rate did make an impact) and changed the sample rate to 8000Hz and the Bit Rate as preset.

Comment: Good to know. But you should have shared a repo with audio asset in order to get help from the community.